# Help on spacing of pillars for a pergola

Tags: measure-theory

I am building a patio.  I have a pergola and need to know where to put my caps for the poles.  it is 8x 12" inside pole to pole.  9x12 is outside pole to pole.  How do I know how far apart to put the caps?  The pillars in which the caps are centered are 22" x 22"

Comment: Please make a drawing.  I don't understand the question.  What is the spacing between the pillars?  Where are the 8x12 and 9x12 measured?

Comment: Thanks.. I think my husband resolved.. he said nevermind.  Thank you